# Vimeo video upload does not return given parameters (POST upload)

Tags: php, prestashop-1.6, vimeo-api

Following the [build and HTML form from the Vimeo docs](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/upload/videos#build-an-html-form-for-your-user%20%22build%20custom%20HTML%20form%20from%20the%20vimeo%20docs) I managed to properly upload a video, but, as setting the video properties/metadata **is not allowed** before the upload is completed I require that some parameters are returned to me.

The docs state:

> We will retain any parameters you have provided, and add one new
>   parameter video_uri.

But they fail to return anything other than the `video_uri`.

My form is composed of this `name`, `privacy.view` and the `file`:

(`Prestashop-smarty tpl`)

```
    <input type="hidden" name="privacy.view" value="nobody">


    <input maxlength="20" class="is_required validate form-control" type="text" id="contentName"
           name="contentName" value="" required/>

    <input type="file" name="file_data" id="exampleInputFile">

    <a href="{$smarty.server.HTTP_REFERER}" class="btn btn-default volver">CANCELAR</a>
    <button type="submit" name="submitFileContent" class="btn btn-default save-profile">
    GUARDAR
    </button>

</form>
```

I expected Vimeo to return `video_uri`, `name` and `privacy.view` but it's only returning the last one.

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

**Edit:** 
I'm passing my own url as the "redirect_url" so no further redirects are being done after vimeo sends the user back to me.

Just in case it can provide anything to the troubleshooting here is the request:

```
$response = $lib->request('/me/videos', array('redirect_url' => Tools::getHttpHost(true).__PS_BASE_URI__."filecontent"), 'POST');
```

Comment: What redirect_url did you specify? Have you verified that those parameters are already missing in the URL vimeo redirects to, and that you did not lose them yourself afterwards (by doing further redirects, or by prestashop’s default routing interfering maybe?)

Comment: Hi @CBroe I'm redirecting to my own url, with no further redirects.

Comment: So your redirect_url contained those parameters and values?

Comment: No, the form contains the values, is it necessary to pass te values in the redirect_url?

Comment: Pretty sure that’s what they mean when they are talking about retaining parameters there. The previous sentence refers to “your previously provided redirect_url”, so “any parameters you have provided” presumably means parameters in that URL.

Comment: I'll try it out, thanks in advance.

Comment: You were right @CBroe, Dashron confirmed the behavior on his reply, regardless, thanks for pointing me in the proper direction :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see how this is confusing in the docs, and will make a note to clear it up.

The parameters we include in the redirect are not user input fields that you request in the form. The parameters we retain in the redirect are any manual querystring parameters you included in the redirect url.

E.g. if you set your redirect_url to be `http://dashron.com?secret_key=abc123`, we will retain the `secret_key` parameter when we redirect the user once the upload is complete.

Comment: I'm also going to see if we can support the functionality you described here, it seems like a great option.

Comment: Good to hear that community feedback/ideas might be added in the future.

Comment: Of course :). Keep an eye out for a slew of upload improvements over the next couple of months!